# Deceleration time logger between frequencies

Tags: time, frequency

i need to measure the air resistance and roll resistance of a vehicle. I plan on using a toothed disc with a proximity sensor which will output a square wave signal in to an arduino. Then I will drive until I reach a certain speed, after which I will disconnect the drive from the wheels and let the vehicle roll until it has reached another certain speed (2 or 3 kph lower than the speed at which I started). By measuring the time it takes to decelerate I can calculate the air and rolling resistance.

I want to use an arduino as the brain box. Once the frequency of the sensor signal drops below a given value the arduino should start measuring time. Once the frequency drops below a second given value the arduino should stop measuring. For example between 25Hz and 20Hz. I would like to change the Frequency (that corresponds to a speed) so i can test at different speeds. I would then want to log the time it took to my pc on the serial monitor. I plan on using an Arduino Mega 2560.

My knowledge of coding in C is very limited so I'm a bit stuck on how I would write such a program. Anybody got any ideas on how to program something by using interrupts? The vehicle on which I want to do this is an Urban Concept car for the Shell Eco-marathon efficiency race.